# Get value of selected field in vb6 data grid

Tags: datagrid, vb6

I'm using data grid for my vb6 project . 
How can I know which record is selected by user?

Answer (score 2):

If the primary key is in the 3rd column, use

```
MyDataGrid.Columns(3).Value
```

That will show you the PK for the selected row.

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` property of the `DataGrid` should be what is currently selected:

```vb
DataGrid1.Text
```

Comment: No . I want to know which record is selected by user

Answer (score 0):

the .Col and .Row properties of the datagrid return the active row and column in the datagrid